# Libraries not working after implementing Webpack (SKD3)

Tags: d3.js, npm, webpack

I am creating a Sankey diagram using [SKD3](https://github.com/fabriciorhs/skd3) . It works fine when i add the libraries the normal way ie:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@4.10.2/build/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/FabricioRHS/skd3/master/build/sk.d3.min.js"></script>
```

After implementing Webpack, i have errors like 'i.createSankey is not a function'

'createSankey' is from the SKD3 library which works fine without webpack

i tried to disable uglyfying the js: `minimize: false` in the webpack.config.js file and then i get : 'skd3_build_sk_d3_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.createSankey is not a function'

This is my simple index.js file:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as sk from "skd3/build/sk.d3.js";
(function() {
    console.log('hi');
    var configSankey = {
        margin: { top: 10, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10 },
        nodes: {
            dynamicSizeFontNode: {
                enabled: true,
                minSize: 14,
                maxSize: 30
            },
            fontSize: 14, // if dynamicSizeFontNode not enabled
            draggableX: false, // default [ false ]
            draggableY: true, // default [ true ]
            colors: d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
        },
        links: {
            formatValue: function(val) {
               return d3.format(",.0f")(val) + ' TWh';
            },
            unit: 'TWh' // if not set formatValue function
        },
        tooltip: {
           infoDiv: true,  // if false display default tooltip
           labelSource: 'Input:',
           labelTarget: 'Output:'
        }
    }   
    var datajson = {nodes: [
     {id: 0, name: "Alice", color: "green"},
     {id: 1, name: "Bob", color: "yellow"},
     {id: 2, name: "Carol", color: "blue"}
    ],
    links: [
     {source: 0, target: 1, value: 1},
     {source: 1, target: 2, value: 1}
    ]};
    var objSankey = sk.createSankey('#sankey', configSankey, datajson);
})();
```

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

I'm new to webpack but i tried searching everywhere for the answer but i can't find it. Need help from you guys. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i managed to solve it but i'm not sure if it's the best solution.

I changed `import * as sk from "skd3/build/sk.d3.js";` to `import {} from 'skd3/build/sk.d3.js';`

I would have a 'd3.tip is not a function error'

To solve that issue i added these 2 lines:

```
import * as skd3tip from 'skd3/build/sk.d3.js';
d3.tip = skd3tip;
```

It works fine after that. hope this can help someone!

And if anyone has a better solution, pls do share. thanks!